# Finder freezes when deleting files across a network

Tags: terminal, finder, network, performance, unix

I have my MacBook 5,2 hooked up to an Ubuntu 10.10 'server' via ethernet.

I've installed `netatalk` (AFP fileserver) and `avahi-daemon` (Bonjour for Linux) on the server. I've disallowed Spotlight from indexing the networked drives.

Everything works as it should, however, from time to time when I delete files that reside on the Ubuntu server from my MacBook, Finder will freeze. I can kill the Finder process. I then try to restart it from the Terminal in this way:

```
open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
```

but this doesn't work. The following error message is printed in the Terminal:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app.
```

The only solution I know of at present is to reboot the MacBook.

So I guess I need to know what my options are here. Is it better for me to use SMB? Or is there a config file I can alter? I have a feeling this bug may be linked to certain disallowed characters in file or pathnames.

Has anyone else experienced this bug?

Cheers.

Comment: Is it actually freezing, or waiting for the default 600-second timeout? Have you ever waited that long to find out?

Comment: Yeh it is actually freezing. I've waited longer than that period. I could put up some logs but I'm unsure where to look.

Comment: We are also experiencing this exact problem on three different macs, all running snow leopard with everything up to date. we have yet to find a solution, and it requires holding down our power buttons to get our (8-month-old) mac pro's up and running again. what should our IT guy be looking for in the network logs? he has not found anything that stood out for him as being a problem.

Comment: Same issue experiences here too. Very annoying ;-(
Running Lion 10.7.2 on two machines.
Deleting files from one machine from a folder on an other machine causes the above mentioned symptoms.
Using the remote mac from it's local keyboard and screen I can work normal on the same folders. Can it have anything todo with time machine running on the remote mac?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Mac OS X are you running?  If you're not on a relatively current Snow Leopard (10.6.x) consider upgrading.

Relevant log files may be found on your Mac OS X client in the `/var/log` directory.  These three may (or may not) contain relevant information (depending on what's actually happening):

- system.log
- kernel.log
- secure.log

Consider also looking in the logs on your server, which may give you additional information.

You can restart the Finder (short of rebooting) in a few ways.
(1) log out, and log back in; or,

(2) restart the Finder in the GUI;

- open the "Force Quit Applications" monitor window
- select "Finder" in the list of running applications
- click "Force Quit"
- Finder will automatically respawn unless hypothetically something dreadfully broken on your system prevents that, in which case I imagine a reboot might be required (I've never seen that happen)

(3) Restart the Finder in a Terminal shell;
The command you describe would be expected to work, but it looks like the open command on your system is guessing wrong about the nature of the Finder.app path that you gave it. Consider launching Disk Utility and running the Repair Permissions.

Note, however, that the Finder should respawn automatically once it's been killed.  The simplest way to restart it in a shell is to:

```
$ killall Finder
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. I'm running 10.6.7. I'll try (1) the next time this happens. Re: (2) - this pretty well describes what's happening here. If I do this I get a graphical error message '-10810' instead of this appearing in the Terminal. Either way Finder doesn't relaunch. Re: (3) - I've already repaired permissions but this hasn't helped the problem. None of those logs seems to show anything of note around the time the last freeze occurred. I'll take a look at the server logs now.